# lamp -- edit PHP file but doesn't change web output -- including die()

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, filesystems

Server is standard Linux server on Amazon Web Services. Cent OS 5/Apache/PHP 5.3. No APC.

It's worked fine for over a year, but now when I edit some but not all PHP files on the server using vi, the changes don't affect the web output.

For example, I edit myfile.php and put a die() at the top, but when I load the page in my web browser, instead of the die() I see the content that would show up if the die() weren't there. svn updating the file in question doesn't help either.

Files are on an Amazon EBS partition symlinked to /var/www/html. Just to reiterate -- this has worked fine for a long time.

Restarting apache didn't help, nor did rebooting the server. What's weird is that it's just some of the files but not all. File ownership/permissions are the same for the "good" and "problem" files.

I'm not a Linux newbie but am at a complete loss with this, and couldn't find anything on Google either. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache after changing the file? It could be your browser happily serving up the same file instead.

Answer (score 0):

May this be because of some PHP op-cache usage? I've seen several time that weird situation when op-cache believes that file is the same (no change was made) so it serves the same old cached content. The same idea for Apache proxy module, check if it's on on your server?

May there also be any filesystem problems that affects webserver ability to see that file is changed?

I'd start with disabling all of webserver modules to check if any of it was the cause (maybe not all, but at lease mod_php, mod_proxy, mod_cgi, if any), then enable it one by one. Then check which PHP extensions are on and play with it.

Comment: A reboot would've cleared any PHP caching...so that's not likely

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's not op-code cache, and there is no APC as well as author stated. But Apache itself is quite a big system which include proxy and cache modules, so I'd started with disabling everything I don't need and try to trace/debug everything from webserver and PHP to browser. Any dumb (maybe even transparent) proxy on the way may give that result as well.

Comment: I will try this and see how it goes -- this stuff sure is nice when it just works :)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and attempt again. I've actually run into this very issue before and it was the browser cache returning the same data and not even consulting the remote server before sending you the cached page.

Comment: Thanks but it's happening on various computers/browsers so it seems to be a server-side issue

Answer (score 0):

Ends up that the weirdness was due to a root path being set weird in httpd conf because the site was being accessed by ssl (port 443) instead of port 80, meaning that page including the die() we were adding wasn't actually being called, but rather one on a different dev system. But the includes on this dev system were still being included, so the die()'s we were putting in them were dying as expected. A very recent config file change on that dev system had introduced the problem.

In other words: user error. Go LAMP!